# npm run start me abre otro proyecto

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, npm, service-workers

Tengo 2 aplicaciones en carpetas separadas, una está en personalProject/umbrella y la otra en personalProject/portfolio. La cuestión es que a umbrella la hice pwa, pero usando Ubuntu 20.04 cuando hago npm run start para iniciar el live-server de mi portfolio, se me ejecuta umbrella, con los service-worker y todo, es rarísimo porque son carpetas distintas y me abre otro proyecto. En portfolio no tengo nada de service-worker ni nada de pwa. El package.json es este:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "live-server"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "live-server": "^1.1.0"
  }
}
```

Debería inicializar portfolio, pero me abre la app de umbrella. Alguno sabe a qué se debe este error? Me tiene muy desconcertado, con el package.json de arriba me sale esto:

```
spamm3r@CMassPC:~/personalProjects/portfolio$ npm start
> start
> live-server
Serving "/home/spamm3r/personalProjects/portfolio" at http://127.0.0.1:8080
Ready for changes
GET /register_serviceWorker.js 404 31.947 ms - 164
GET /sw.js 404 3.239 ms - 144
```

Esos GET de sw que tira no sé de donde los saca, porque en ningún lado de la carpeta del proyecto trabajo con esto. Quizás se me instaló algo global? Pero de ser así debería pasar con mis demás proyectos, y sólo hace esto con portfolio. Aparte ahí me muestra que abrió portfolio en el 8080, pero vas a esa dirección y está umbrella ejecutada.

Ya probé limpiar la caché de ubuntu, borrar node-modules de portfolio y hacer nuevamente npm i, pero sigue igual.

Comment: será caché de tu navegador? ya lo intentaste borrar? Porque según los logs si sirve la carpeta correcta

Comment: package.json completo, por favor. No es evidente cómo están ahí las dependencias y si puede estar jalando algo, de alguna forma.

Comment: @Pipe Era la caché del navegador sí, al eliminar todo el problema se solucionó. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Con mucho gusto ;)

Answer (score 0):

Lo que creo que pasa aca es que hay un choque entre los puertos. Es decir, ambos proyectos escuchan al mismo puerto, esto quiere decir que el puerto **npm start** en la carpeta del proyecto **portfolio**, se inicia el servidor en el puerto 8080, pero parece que otro servidor ya está escuchando en ese puerto, en este caso seria el **proyecto umbrella**, ¿me explico?.

Para cambiar el puerto en el que se ejecuta el servidor perteneciente a la carpeta portfolio, se logra **editando el archivo package.json**. Puedes agregar una línea en los scripts para decir el puerto en el que deseas que se ejecute el servidor de live-server.

Por lo tanto la modificacion de tu json parasaria de estar asi:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "live-server"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "live-server": "^1.1.0"
  }
}
```

A estar asi:

```
{
  "scripts": {
        "start": ""live-server --port=8081""
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "live-server": "^1.1.0"
      }
    }
```

Esto inicia el puerto **8081**, que debería estar disponible ya que el servidor en **8080** es utilizado por el **proyecto umbrella**. Dicho esto creo que deberia ser suficiente para solucionar el problema de los puertos.

Ahora, los archivos **sw.js** y **register_serviceWorker.js**, si no tienes nada relacionado con Service Workers en tu proyecto portfolio, es probable que los archivos estén siendo solicitados por algún otro script como proyecto umbrella (*me gusta el nombre*).

Comment: Lo de los puertos es raro, porque una vez que un proceso atiende otro puerto, otro proceso no puede usar el mismo puerto (el SO deberia prohibirselo)...